# Datepicker disable next 2 days if past 3pm, next 3 days if friday past 3pm and next 1 day if current date is a specific date

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

Trying to find a solution by myself, but it has been hard.
I have a form field for delivery date selecion, with some conditions, like disable the next day if past 3pm, and next 2 days if friday past 3pm.

After searching for some solutions, I wrote the code bellow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#date-pick').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'YYYY MM dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: +1,
        constrainInput: true
   });            

    var dateTime = new Date();
    var hour = dateTime.getHours();
    var dayOfWeek = dateTime.getDay(); 

    if(dateTime.getHours() >= 15) {
        $('#date-pick').datepicker( "option", "minDate", "+2" )
    }
    else if(dayOfWeek == 5  &&  hour >= 15) {
        $('#date-pick').datepicker( "option", "minDate", "+3" );
    }
    });

</script>
```

But it's not working, just for the next day.

I found this solution for disabling "next 2 days if past 3pm", but either don't know how to add the "**next 3 days if friday past 3pm**" in this context...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#date-pick').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: new Date().getHours() >= 15 ? 2 : 1,
        constrainInput: true
     });            
  });
</script>
```

Notice that some people use beforeShowDay.

Found a solution, maybe not the best, but it's working.

```
    jQuery('#date-pick').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: new Date().getHours() >= 15 ? 2 : 1,

    beforeShow : function(){
    var dateTime = new Date();
    var hour = dateTime.getHours();
    var dayOfWeek = dateTime.getDay(); //check the day of the week
        if(dayOfWeek == 5 && hour >= 15) {
            jQuery("#date-pick").datepicker( "option", "minDate", "+4" )
        }
        else if(dayOfWeek == 6) {
            jQuery("#date-pick").datepicker( "option", "minDate", "+3" )
        }
        else if(dayOfWeek == 0) {
            jQuery("#date-pick").datepicker( "option", "minDate", "+2" );
        }
    }

   });
```

But remembered that I have one more condition, that is the fourth one:
**Disable the next day if current day is a specific day, like holidays.**

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you add some working code in JS fiddle. Would be easier for us to help :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Rahul!
Actually this test page was built in wp, but I'll try to convert it to html to be available at JS fiddle.

Comment: Not the whole page but maybe only minimal part of it.

Comment: Hi Rahul, just shared a solution. Thank you!